# In App Purchase is working, but I'm having trouble changing the UIButton image after the payment is successful

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have my in app purchase up and running fine. This is what I have in InAppPurchaseObserver.m:

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            // Item was successfully purchased!

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased" ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
            break;

case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            // Verified that user has already paid for this item.
            // Ideal for restoring item across all devices of this customer.

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased" ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
            break;
```

In my ViewController I'm doing this:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"]) {

  [energeeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_unlocked_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

That works as soon as I restart the app, but I would like the button image to change right after the in app purchase completes.

How do I make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send a notification of sorts to the viewcontroller when that value is changed so it can reload that specific image

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DZCustomNotification" object:nil];
// put this right after you change the user defaults




// put this in the initializer of your viewcontroller
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(purchasedChanged:) name:@"DZCustomNotification" object:nil];

// create this instance method in your viewcontroller class

- (void)purchasedChanged:(NSNotification *)notif {
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased"]) {

        [energeeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_unlocked_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

There ya go!

Comment: use NSNotificationCenter
add your viewcontroller as an observer of a notification name and then send the notification when you change the value

Comment: any chance you write that out with some code in an answer? thanks so much!